# Require and Angular RouteProvider undefined

Tags: angularjs

I get undefined in the following code when trying to load via require.js

HTML

```
  <script data-main="application/main" src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.14/minified/require.js"></script>
```

main.js

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "application", 
    paths: {
        angular: 'https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular',
        angularRoute: 'https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular-route'
    },

    shim: {
        angular: {exports: 'angular' } ,
        angularRoute: { deps: ['angular'], exports: 'angularRoute' },
    }
});

require(['app', 'routesBoot'], function (app) {
    app.init();
});
```

app.js

```
define(['angular'], function (angular) {

    var app = angular.module('reporterdashboard', []);

    app.init = function () {
        console.log('app.init called');
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['reporterdashboard']);
    };

    return app;
  });
```

routesBoot.js

```
require(['app', 'angularRoute'], function (app, angularRouterParam) {

    //put my routes in here, using angularRouterParam
    //but angularRouterParam = undefined

    return app.config(function (angularRouterParam) {
        angularRouterParam.when('/page2', { controller: 'Page2Controller', templateUrl: 'page2.html' });
    });
});
```

When I inspect angularRouterParam passed into routesBoot it's undefined. What have I done wrong ?
I'm basically trying to split my app and therefore, placing my routes in their own file (controllers, directives etc will live in their own boot .js files). I'm letting require.js look after all my .js file loading as can be seen in main.js.
The code in routesBoot is not syntactically correct at the moment as I'm stuck with the problem of an undefined angularRouterParam

Comment: I'm not sure but should'nt you define app in app.js if you return the app and not angular that already exists and is a dependancy?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was out side of the code I've posted here. I was loading a directive first into the index.html (View First). This directive was loading other dependencies. The project is quite large, some 40 .js files. My restructuring with require was at fault.